# How to create a face via geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Let's say in my geometry that I have 3 vertices. Is there a way to combine those into a single face using geometry nodes? I was unable to find any node like "join vertices" or "create face".

Comment: You can join vertices in same(near) position by merge node

Comment: Triangles / other planar convex faces are fine ( _Convex Hull_ ). But as soon as you want any concavities, you need to disambiguate the order of vertices, somehow. How would you want to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your use case is really only about exactly three vertices, then you can create the required face with `Mesh Circle`, and transfer the positions of the vertices with `Transfer Attribute`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use convex hull, there is a small problem, it creates 2 faces. Separate them with a "split edges", remove one of the faces with "delete geometry" according to the index, then merge rest of the duplicated vertices with "merge by distance".
[image]

[image]